# How to check if the Hive query in running on Tez

Tags: apache, hive, hortonworks-data-platform

I have used the below command to set the execution engine as Tez.

> set hive.execution.engine=tez;

I had run a query to check the performance on both MR and TEZ separately.

I did not find any difference plus i couldnt see the containers in TEZ.

So how can I confirm that I am running my query on Tez.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There will be application type column in Resource Manager UI accessible on 8088 port which has values like TEZ  or Mapreduce.Example:http://:8088

-Arun voma